# Jquery/XML .find() function to retrieve xml data

Tags: xml, jquery

This may seem trivial, but I can't figure it out how to 1) retrieve the XML data and 2) find specific content within a child element with this specific XML structure!

XML:

```
<UploadResults>
  <Header>
    <Header_ID>1</Header_ID> 
    <PlanYear>2015</PlanYear> 
    <PlanVersion>FP01</PlanVersion> 
  </Header>
  <ErrorSet>
    <Row>
      <Row_Id>0</Row_Id> 
      <Error_String>Validation successful with Zero Errors</Error_String> 
    </Row>
    <Row>
       ...
    </Row>
  </ErrorSet>
</UploadResults>
```

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "testurl",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('UploadResults').each(function(){  
            var errMsg = $(this).find('Error_String').text(); // set variable as content in child 'Error_String'
            $(".validationView").append($(this).text());    // display all xml data on div class
            if (errMsg=="Validation successful with Zero Errors") {
                $("span.proceedBTN").show();
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

The script works with the following XML Structure so I am not sure why the script doesn't return any data from the first xml structure. (Of course, I would change the root name from UploadResults to Rowsets)

```
<Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
    <Columns>
      <Column Description="Header_Id"/>
      <Column Description="PlanYear"/>
      <Column Description="PlanVersion"/> 
    </Columns>
    <Row>
      <Row_Id>0</Row_Id> 
      <Error_String>Validation successful with Zero Errors</Error_String> 
    </Row>
    <Row>
       ...
    </Row>
  </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Comment: Looks correct... what exactly isnt working?

Comment: it did not return any results from the xml page. I am adding another XML structure that works well with this script... I am not sure if its because of another level in the XML structure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to find upload results, its the root of your document.

```
$(xml).each(function(){  
    var errMsg = $(this).find('Error_String').text(); // set variable as content in child 'Error_String'
    $(".validationView").append($(this).text());    // display all xml data on div class
    if (errMsg=="Validation successful with Zero Errors") {
            $("span.proceedBTN").show();
    } 
 });
```

I just ran it and it worked here is a [JSFiddle that shows it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/cNeRG/).

Comment: I removed the root, but its still not returning any data from my XML. I updated my post to include an XML structure that this script works well with... however, I need it to work with the first xml file.